# CSS selector for an element's text without child elements

Tags: css-selectors

I'm trying to pull out the text of a parent element without its child elements texts

```
<div>
   Text A
   <button>Text B</button>
   <button>Text C</button>
</div>
```

I need only the "Text A" but all I manage to get is:
"  Text A
  Text B
  Text C  "

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: so what about the button ? do you want to hide it? or do you want it on net line.

Comment: When I use $("div").textContent, I get all the text.
I want the buttons to be displayed on the HTML but to pull only the "Text A".